# Why upload file did not work with ion-content? and work if I remove ion-content

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am new with ionic, and I want to upload picture, thus I use "ng-file-upload" to upload my picture.
but the code not work only if I remove "ion-content". my template is:

```
    <ion-view view-title="IQ Marketplace" ng-controller="SellCtrl">
    <ion-content class="padding" >
    <div class="list">
      <form   ng-submit="submitAds()" name="form" novalidate>


        <label class="item item-input">
          <span class="input-label">Picture</span>
      <input type="file" ngf-select ng-model="file" name="file" ngf-pattern="'image/*'"
        accept="image/*" >
        </label>
    <input type="submit" class="button button-block button-positive" value="Save" ng-disabled="form.$invalid">
    </form>

    </div><!--list-->

    </ion-content>
    </ion-view>
```

And my controller is:

```
.controller('SellCtrl', function($scope,Upload) {

                  $scope.submitAds = function() {
                    console.log("ayman "+ $scope.file)
                      $scope.upload($scope.file);
                  };
                   $scope.upload = function (file) {
                      Upload.upload({
                          url: 'http://localhost/IQM/public/ads',
                          data: {file: file, 'username': $scope.test}
                      }).then(function (resp) {
                          console.log('Success ' + resp.config.data.file.name + 'uploaded. Response: ' + resp.data);
                      }, function (resp) {
                          console.log('Error status: ' + resp.status);
                      }, function (evt) {
                          var progressPercentage = parseInt(100.0 * evt.loaded / evt.total);
                          console.log('progress: ' + progressPercentage + '% ' + evt.config.data.file.name);
                      });
                  };
  });
```

This code gives me this exception:

```
   TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
   at controllers.js:84
   at ionic.bundle.js:23476
   at Scope.$eval (ionic.bundle.js:24673)
   at Scope.$digest (ionic.bundle.js:24484)
   at ionic.bundle.js:24712
   at completeOutstandingRequest (ionic.bundle.js:14221)
   at ionic.bundle.js:14493
```

But when I remove the "ion-content" the upload will successful.
What is the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you have introduced the [Ionic Framework](http://ionicframework.com/).

This apparently is angular's `scope` problem.

You define a `ng-model="file"` inside `ion-content`. While `ion-content` creates a new `scope`, so you cannot retrieve the variable `file` directly.

Please refer to the [doc](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionContent/), and it says that:

> Be aware that this directive gets its own child scope.

You can use `dot notations` like:

```
// controller
$scope.data = {}

// html
<ion-content class="padding" >
    ...
    <input ng-model="data.file" />
    ...
</ion-content>
```

And then you can get the value by `$scope.data.file`.

The root reason is about AngularJS's `scope` conception.

You can read these articles for more information.

- http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/problem-with-ion-content-and-scope-vars-inside-function/1811
- https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes

Answer (score 0):

I solve the problem by adding $parent,thus it become ng-model="$parent.file"

```
<ion-view view-title="IQ Marketplace" ng-controller="SellCtrl">
<ion-content class="padding" >
<div class="list">
  <form   ng-submit="submitAds()" name="form" novalidate>


    <label class="item item-input">
      <span class="input-label">Picture</span>
  <input type="file" ngf-select ng-model="$parent.file" name="file" ngf-pattern="'image/*'"
    accept="image/*" >
    </label>
<input type="submit" class="button button-block button-positive" value="Save" ng-disabled="form.$invalid">
</form>
</div><!--list-->
</ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Comment: This implementation depends on the DOM structure. If the html has more nested child scopes, you have to add many '$parent's. It is practical but not the best practice.

Comment: You are totally right, thus I will use your method instead of this ; )